# Haskell infinite recursion in list comprehension

Tags: list, haskell, recursion, repeat, infinite

I am trying to define a function that accepts a point (x,y) as input, and returns an infinite list corresponding to recursively calling

> P = (u^2 − v^2 + x, 2uv + y)

The initial values of u and v are both 0.

- The first call would be

  > P = (0^2 - 0^2 + 1, 2(0)(0) + 2) = (1,2)
- Then that resulting tuple (1,2) would be the next values for u and v, so then it would be

  > P = (1^2 - 2^2 + 1, 2(1)(2) + 2) = (-2,6)

and so on.

I'm trying to figure out how to code this in Haskell. This is what I have so far:

```
o :: Num a =>(a,a) -> [(a,a)]
o (x,y) = [(a,b)| (a,b)<- [p(x,y)(x,y)]]   
  where p(x,y)(u,v) = ((u^2)-(v^2)+x,(2*u*v)+y)
```

I'm really not sure how to make this work. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: [`iterate P (0, 0)`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:iterate)?

Comment: Please don't remove your example code. Everyone starts out somewhere. There's no need to be ashamed of it :)

Comment: @Rhymoid, are you suggesting my elementary school Logo, BASIC, and Turbo Pascal code may have left something to be desired? I have only ever written perfect code myself, and I expect the same of everyone else. Programming is Serious Business, and there's no room for any mistakes!

Answer (score 8):

Let's first ignore the exact question you have, and focus on getting the loop working. What you want, essentially, is to have something that takes some initial value `iv` (namely, `(0, 0)` for `(u, v)`), and returns the list

```hs
f iv : f (f iv) : f (f (f iv)) : f (f (f (f iv))) : ...
```

for some function `f` (constructed from your `p` and `(x, y)`). Moreover, you want the result to reuse the previously computed elements of the list. If I would write a function myself that does this, it might looke like this (but maybe with some different names):

```hs
looper :: (a -> a) -> a -> [a]
looper f iv = one_result : more_results
  where
    one_result   = f iv
    more_results = looper f one_result
```

But, of course, I would first [look](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%28a+-%3E+a%29+-%3E+a+-%3E+%5Ba%5D) if a function with that type exists. It does: it's called [`Data.List.iterate`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:iterate). The only thing it does wrong is the first element of the list will be `iv`, but that can be easily fixed by using `tail` (which is fine here: as long as your iteration function terminates, `iterate` will always generate an infinite list).

---

Let's now get back to your case. We established that it'll generally look like this:

```hs
o :: Num a => (a, a) -> [(a, a)]
o (x, y) = tail (iterate f iv)
  where
    f (u, v) = undefined
    iv = undefined
```

As you indicated, the initial value of `(u, v)` is `(0, 0)`, so that's what our definition of `iv` will be. `f` now has to call `p` with the `(x, y)` from `o`'s argument and the `(u, v)` for that iteration:

```hs
o :: Num a => (a, a) -> [(a, a)]
o (x, y) = tail (iterate f iv)
  where
    f (u, v) = p (x, y) (u, v)
    iv = (0, 0)
    p = undefined
```

It's as simple as that: the `(x, y)` from `o`'s definition is actually in scope in the `where`-clause. You could even decide to merge `f` and `p`, and end up with

```hs
o :: Num a => (a, a) -> [(a, a)]
o (x, y) = tail (iterate p iv)
  where
    iv = (0, 0)
    p (u, v) = (u^2 - v^2 + x, 2 * u * v + y)
```

---

Also, may I suggest that you use `Data.Complex` for your application? This makes the constraints on `a` a bit stricter (you need `RealFloat a`, because of `Num.signum`), but in my opinion, it makes your code much easier to read:

```hs
import Data.Complex
import Data.List (iterate)

{- ... -}

o :: Num (Complex a) => Complex a -> [Complex a]
o c = tail (iterate p iv)
  where
    iv = 0  -- or "0 :+ 0", if you want to be explicit
    p z = z^2 + c
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That makes a lot of sense!

Answer (score 0):

You want:

1. To construct a list `[(u, v)]` with the head of this list equal `(0, 0)`
2. And then `map` this list with the function `\(u, v) -> (u^2 - v^2 + x, 2 * u * v + y)`, appending results of this function to the list.

We can write this function as described:

```
func :: (Num t) => (t, t) -> [(t, t)]
func (x, y) = (0, 0) : map functionP (func (x, y))
    where functionP (u, v) = (u^2 - v^2 + x, 2 * u * v + y)

GHCi > take 5 $ func (1, 2)
     > [(0,0),(1,2),(-2,6),(-31,-22),(478,1366)]
```

Comment: Are you sure that this performs as efficiently as a solution based on `iterate`?