# haskell takes a (x,y) and return a infinite list with the a definition of Orbit(x,y)

Tags: haskell, mandelbrot

There is a function P(x,y) defined as:

```
P(x,y)(u,v) = (u^2 - v^2 + x, 2uv + y)
```

and define Orbit O(x,y) of a point (x,y) to be an infinite list of items:

```
O(x,y) = {(0,0), P(x,y)(0,0), P(x,y)(P(x,y)(0,0)), P(x,y)(P(x,y)(P(x,y)(0,0))),..}
```

So I need to write Haskell function that takes a single point (x,y) as an argument and returns an infinite list corresponding to O(x,y).

I try to write this with a helper function where:

```
orbit :: (Eq i, Num i) => i -> i -> [i]
orbit x y = (x,y) : orbit(p(x,y)(u,v))
where p(x,y)(u,v) = phelp x y

phelp u v = ((0^2)-(0^2)+x,(2*0*0)+y)
```

but I keep going wrong with whatever I modify. Can someone else help me and explain why it works? I think it needs to use recursion.

Comment: Is this a Mandelbrot set computation, by any chance?

Comment: This looks familiar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39809592/haskell-infinite-recursion-in-list-comprehension

Comment: @melpomene Good spotting

Comment: So many thanks that I try to search and find nothing related, the question name of that one is so much different of what I try to search.! That solve my problem !