# python generate a infinite list with certain condition

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, yield

I know there is generator yield in python like:

```
def f(n): 
    x = n
    while True:
        yield x
        x = x+1
```

So I try to convert this haskell function into python without using iterate: [Haskell infinite recursion in list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39809592/haskell-infinite-recursion-in-list-comprehension)

I'm not sure how to define base case in python, also not sure how to combine if statement with this yield staff! here is what I try to do:

```
def orbit(x,y):
    while True:
        yield p (u,v)
        p (u,v) = (u^2 - v^2 + x, 2 * u * v + y)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont see where you're getting the `p` from. As far as I can see you can almost literally translate it from Haskell:

```
def orbit(x, y):
    u, v = 0, 0
    while True:
        u, v = u**2 − v**2 + x, 2*u*v + y
        yield u, v
```

In their example, calling the function as `orbit(1, 2)`, `u` will be bound to `1` and `v` to `2` in the first round, then that (`(1, 2)`) is yielded. In the next iteration, `u = 1**2 - 2**2 + 1 = 1 - 4 + 1 = -2` and `v = 2*1*2 + 2 = 6`.

Comment: this is so similar! almost exactly same, I think I suppose this in a difficult way. btw, thanks a lot!